# Is there a way to do an astroquery conesearch with a magnitude limit?

Tags: python, coordinates, astronomy, magnitude, astroquery

Goal: I would like to return an astropy table of star coordinates with magnitudes below a specified number.

Currently: I am using astroquery.vo_conesearch.conesearch to get the table of star coordinates and magnitudes and then afterwards removing stars whose magnitude is above a specified limit. It is a huge waste of time to get every single object within the cone only to remove a good chunk of them.

Question: Is there a way I can give astroquery (conesearch or any other similar functions) a specific magnitude limit such that it will search for and return only the coordinates of stars below the magnitude limit? It doesn't have to be astroquery specifically; if there's another method to achieve this, I would like to know.

If the answer is no, are there any faster ways to get the original table of stars (what should I use instead of conesearch)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. See http://cta-observatory.github.io/ctapipe/api/ctapipe.utils.get_bright_stars.html

It is a function which takes the Yale Bright Stars Catalog and returns an astropy table for stars below the magnitude limit.